# Error when saving data to a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I am trying to get data to save to a JSON file however I keep getting the following errors and I can't seem to figure out where I have gone wrong. When running my code the JSON file is created however the data is not saved to the file and I get errors (see image).The problem is under the "save password" section.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import choice, randint, shuffle
import pyperclip
import json
# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #

def generate_password():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

    password_letters = [choice(letters) for _ in range(randint(8, 10))]
    password_symbols = [choice(symbols) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]
    password_numbers = [choice(numbers) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]

    password_list = password_letters + password_symbols + password_numbers
    shuffle(password_list)
    password = "".join(password_list)
    password_entry.insert(0, password)
    pyperclip.copy(password)


# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #
def save():
    websites = website_entry.get()
    email = email_entry.get()
    passwords = password_entry.get()
    new_data = {
        website: {
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
        }
    }

    if len(websites) == 0 or len(passwords) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Oops", message="Please make sure you haven't left any fields empty")
    else:
        with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
            json.dump(new_data, data_file)
            website_entry.delete(0, END)
            password_entry.delete(0, END)




# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)
lock = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=lock)

website = Label(text="Website:")
website.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="e")

email_user_name = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_user_name.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="e")

password = Label(text="Password:")
password.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="e")

website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.focus()
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.insert(END, "michaeljohnacton@gmail.com")
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

password_entry = Entry(width=35)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="w")

generate_button = Button(text="Generate Password", width=29, command=generate_password)
generate_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

add_button = Button(text="Add", width=29, command=save)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=5, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
window.mainloop()
```

LIST OF ERRORS:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"C:\Users\mikea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

File "C:\Users\mikea\Downloads\password-manager-start\main.py", line 40, in save
    json.dump(new_data, data_file)

File"C:\Users\mikea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:

File "C:\Users\mikea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)

File "C:\Users\mikea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks

File "C:\Users\mikea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks

File "C:\Users\mikea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)

File "C:\Users\mikea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Label is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Please don't post the picture of an error. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it. Pictures aren't searchable or copyable, and the visually impaired can't read them at all.

Comment: @BryanOakley I fixed it. Thanks for the heads up not to post pictures of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a label with name as website and using it as key in the dictionary. Change from website: to "website":